# How to get input value via v-model in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a button that generates inputs via a click event. I want to get the input values via v-model instead of $ref but I get that the value is undefined, how can I achieve that? Here is my code:

```
<div class="price-round-creation-containe" v-for="(shareholder, index) in shareholders" :key="index">
          <div>
            <input v-model="shareholder.username" :name="`shareholders[${index}][username]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
          </div>
            <div>
            <input v-model="shareholder.investment" :name="`shareholders[${index}][investment]`" type="text" class="form-control input" >
            <i v-if="shareholder.dynamic" class="fas fa-trash"  @click="deleteItem(index)"/>
          </div>
         
        </div>
```

my js where the data goes:

```
shareholders: [
      {
        investment: "Investment",
        username: "Username",
        dynamic: false
      },
    ],
```

and the way that I push the inputs:

```
  createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {
    this.shareholders.push({
      username: "Username",
      investment: "Investment",
      dynamic: true
      })
     },
```

and how I try to access the value:

```
      let username = this.shareholders.username;
```

and the function that gets the values:

```
getPricedRoundFormData() {
      const totalShareAmount = this.$refs.pricedRoundForm.roundAmount.value.replace(/,/g,"");
      const shareType = this.$refs.pricedRoundForm.shareType.value.replace(/,/g,"");
      let username = this.$refs.pricedRoundForm.username.value.replace(/,/g,"");
      let investment = this.$refs.pricedRoundForm.investment.value.replace(/,/g,"");
      
      let usernames, investments;
      if (!username.length) {
        usernames = [username.value];
        investments = [investment.value];
      } else {
        usernames = Array.from(username).map((el) => el.value);
        investments = Array.from(investment).map((el) => el.value);
      }
      return { usernames, investments, shareType, totalShareAmount };
    },
```

and the submit function:

```
  async submitPricedRound() {
      this.showNewPriceRoundDialog = false;
      const pricedRoundData = this.getPricedRoundFormData();
      this.addPricedRound(pricedRoundData);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this.shareholders` is an array of objects, access a particular shareholder via index:

```js
this.shareholders[index].username;
```

For example, in your `deleteItem` method:

```js
methods: {
  deleteItem(index) {
    /* do something with */ this.shareholders[index].username;
  }
}
```

*Edit, replying to comments:*

If you want an array of all usernames, you could do this:

```js
const usernames = this.shareholders.map(s => s.username);
```